# Angular 2 RC6 - Cross origin requests error

Tags: javascript, angular

After migrating to RC6, I started getting a bunch of errors when initialising my application.

At first, I was hitting the [traceur not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294548/angular2-upgrade-to-rc6-traceur-not-found) error, which I've solved.
I've added the correct packages to `package.json` and pointed `system.config.js` to work with the UMD files.

However, now I get a bunch of other errors like the one bellow (more precisely, I get 121 errors.

`zone.js:1241 XMLHttpRequest cannot load npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.scheduleTask
(...)
33system.src.js:373 Assertion failed: loading or loaded`

What's the deal with this? How can I solve it?
I've explicitly set my "server" requests (on the service classes) to explicitly define the Headers but I'm still hitting this issue.

Anyone else faced the same problem?

#### EDIT

Adding system.config.js and package.json for clarification

System.config.js

```
 (function(global) {
    System.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'node_modules'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      'app': 'www/build', // 'dist',

      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',

      // angular testing umd bundles
      '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',

      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'primeng': 'npm:primeng',
      'lodash': 'npm:lodash',
      'angular2-jwt': 'npm:angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',

      'routes': 'app/routes',
      'services': 'app/services'
    },

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {main: 'app.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
      rxjs: {defaultExtension: 'js'},
      primeng: {defaultExtension: 'js'},
      lodash: {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
      'angular2-jwt': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
    }
    })
    })(this);
```

package.json

```
    {
     "name": "my-admin",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "description": "Admin UI",
     "private": true,
     "main": "",
     "scripts": {
       "postinstall": "npm run typings install",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
        "typings": "typings"
     },
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
      "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
      "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
      "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
      "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
      "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
      "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
      "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.22",
      "chart.js": "^2.2.1",
      "core-js": "^2.4.1",
      "lodash": "^4.15.0",
      "ng2-translate": "^2.4.2",
      "primeng": "^1.0.0-beta.15",
      "primeui": "^4.1.12",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
      "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
      "systemjs": "^0.19.27",
      "timsort": "^0.3.0",
      "tslint": "^3.13.0",
      "zone.js": "^0.6.21",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
      "del": "^2.2.0",
      "eslint": "^3.1.0",
      "eslint-config-google": "^0.6.0",
      "fs": "0.0.2",
      "gulp": "^3.9.1",
      "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
      "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
      "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
      "gulp-insert": "^0.5.0",
      "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
      "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
      "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
      "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
      "http-server": "^0.9.0",
      "run-sequence": "1.1.5",
      "typescript": "^1.8.10",
      "typings": "^1.0.4"
     },
     "repository": {
      "type": "git",
    "url": "<url>"
  },
  "author": "Myself",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "<url>#readme"
}
```

Comment: npmcdn.com needs to bechanged to unpkg.com if you use it.

Comment: Does the `platform-browser-dynamic` package present in the `node_modules` directory? it is configured correctly in the `systemjs.config.js`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Hi, I don't use it, but tks for pointing it out

Comment: @KesemDavid yes it is. see the edit :)

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013838/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-issue-in-angular2