# Angular 2 cannot load npm:@angular packages

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, systemjs

I am trying to run an angular 2 app through visual studio 2015 using typescript.
I am using systemjs (version v0.19.41) to load all required packages.

here is my system.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {


        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },

    map: {
        app: 'app',

        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

        'rxjs':'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api',          
        'primeng': '/node_modules/primeng'
    },
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        primeng: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
    });
})(this);
```

When viewing the console I see a list of these types of messages:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

After searching online, I found a post that mentions the same issue but has 
no resolution:

[Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes issue in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013838/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-issue-in-angular2][1])

My question that I have is what type of URL is 'npm:@angular'. Is this interpreted by systemjs and converted into a valid url?

Comment: `paths` in `system.config.js` tells systemjs that `npm:` should be replaced with `node_modules/`, so  `map` as a result should give relative url like `node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js` for `@angular/core` module referenced in the code (`@angular` is just a folder in `node_modules`). From the error message it looks like `paths` setting in `system.config.js` has no effect, no idea why.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if I understand correctly, where ever this app is deployed, the node_modules directory has to be copied to that environment as well?

Comment: Yes either node_modules should be deployed and accessible, or modules from it should be bundled together with the app code using something like systemjs builder or webpack or [angular cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#bundling).